# Confused by Spring's JSON serialization

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have an application written in Java with Spring Boot and Spring MVC that responds to a get request with an object that contains a byte array:

```
public HashedPasswordSpec get() {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail("example@example.com");
    return user.getHashedPasswordSpec();
}
```

on the client side I attempt to automatically deserialize it using the same class:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HashedPasswordSpec spec = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/v1/hashed-password-spec", HashedPasswordSpec.class);
```

That fails with this error:

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 10 path $.salt
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter.readTypeToken(GsonHttpMessageConverter.java:161)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 10 path $.salt
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    ... 42 more
```

`salt` is the `byte[]`. When I instead get a string and print it out:

```
String spec = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/v1/hashed-password-spec", String.class);
System.out.println(spec);
```

I see this:

```
{"salt":"2GKm9SVxsvLmwaydk8heK/eB94HoPR21+2rTmKMjWo0=","algorithm":"SCrypt","cost":12,"blockSize":8,"parallelization":1,"keyLength":256}
```

As you can see, salt is serialized as a Base64 but that's not what Gson does out of the box with byte arrays. Does Spring Boot extend Gson to serialize byte arrays as Base64 strings? If so, does RestTemplate omit this extension? Are they incompatible with each other? What am I missing here?

Comment: Spring registers default serializers/deserializers based on what's in the classpath. Does your server classpath contain Jackson? Does your client classpath only contain Gson?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: both the server and the client contain Gson in the classpath, although not directly, through another dependency. I'm not sure about Jackson.

Comment: Jackson, by default, serializes `byte[]` to base64 strings, iirc. Gson does not. So your server most likely has Jackson on its classpath (which is higher in its registration order for serializers than Gson).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: good to know... the server definitely has Jackson in its classpath (a spring component pulls it). I added Jackson to the client and  I get exactly the same error, with Gson trying to parse the JSON payload. Does RestTemplate not pick Jackson over Gson when present?

Comment: If you are instantiating `RestTemplate` with its parameterless constructor, and both libraries are on the classpath, it only registers Jackson. It does so [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java#L185). Check how you're initializing `RestTemplate`.

Comment: Just calling RestTemplate()... mmhh... to the debugger! brb

Comment: Ah... I was missing some other parts of jackson. Yes, that was it. Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis. Do you want to add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`RestTemplate`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java#L185) and [Spring MVC's infrastructure](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L819) register, by default, various serializers/deserializers depending on what they find on the classpath.

Specifically, they're looking for Jackson and Gson for its JSON serialization, both preferring Jackson if it's found.

In your case, the fact that your server is serializing the `byte[]` to a Base64 string hints that it's using Jackson since that's its default strategy (see `ByteArraySerializer`).

And we can see from your error log that `RestTemplate` is failing to parse the JSON with `Gson`. `Gson` does not use, nor expect, Base64 strings for a field of type `byte[]`, it just expects a JSON array containing numbers.

Your client is therefore not registering Jackson as a serializer, either because it's not on the classpath or because you've registered a custom list of `HttpMessageConverter` instances that don't contain the Jackson variant.

Comment: `Jackson2` has high order than `gson`. So what is the solution to get around this issue? What you have to do for `gson` to register instead of `Jackson2`? Remove Jackson2? Thx

Comment: @MinhKieu Yes, you can either remove Jackson from the classpath or you can manually decide and register the `HttpMessageConverter` instances you want.